# Magento Load static block into php file

Tags: php, magento

I have created a custom form that loads on an iframe. It also has the send.php form which is a custom file also. I need as a thank you message though to load the content from a static block so client can change it.

How can I load the text from the static block into a custom php file?

Thank you

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this:

```
require_once 'path/to/'.'Mage.php'; //replace 'path/to' with the relative path to your Mage.app file
echo Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('some_block_id')->toHtml();
```

Comment: `Mage::getBlockSingleton('cms/block')` does the same thing (`Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock()`)

Comment: I have this error now

Fatal error: Class 'Mage' not found in ../submit.php on line 41

Comment: this worked! thank you so much. I added this on top of the file

<?php require_once('app/Mage.php'); //Path to Magento
umask(0);
Mage::app();

And the echo on my echo code!

Thank you :-)

Answer (score 6):

{BLOCK_IDENTIFIER} is the id of the static block:

```
echo Mage::getModel('cms/block')->load('{BLOCK_IDENTIFIER}')->getContent();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I get this error

"Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in ../submit.php on line 41"

This is that part

        if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))
{
 echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('{thankyou}')->toHtml();
}

else
{
 print "Mail cannot send to administration";
}

Line 41 is the echo part

Comment: I changed the implementation to a static functioncall. Try it again please.

Comment: And unless your block-identifier contains the {}, you can ommit them ;)

Comment: you mean adding the same thing without the {} ?

Comment: You will have to make sure Magento is loaded on the page where you want the code to work. By using a controller to reach your template, or by including app/Mage.php. And yes, without the {}.

Answer (score 1):

I used the following if it helps someone else

```
require_once ($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/dev/app/Mage.php"); //remove dev if you want the Mage.php from root

  echo Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')>setBlockId('some_block_id')->toHtml();
```